# How to close sqlite connection in daemon thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sqlite, python-multithreading

I have multiple threads that process data and puts it on a queue, and a single thread that takes data from a queue and then saves it to a database.

I think the following will cause a memory leak:

```
class DBThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, myqueue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.myqueue = myqueue

    def run(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
        c = conn.cursor()

        while True:
            data = myqueue.get()
            if data:
                c.execute("INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES (?)", (data,))
                conn.commit()

            self.myqueue.task_done()

        #conn.close()    <--- never reaches this point

q = Queue.Queue()

# Create other threads
....

# Create DB thread
t = DBThread(q)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()

q.join()
```

I can't put the `conn.close()` in the while loop, because I think that will close the connection on the first loop. I can't put it in the `if data:` statement, because then it won't save data that may be put in the queue later.

Where do I close the db connection? If I don't close it, won't this cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a sentinel value that will not appear in your normal data, e.g. `None`, you can signal the thread to stop and close the database connection in a `finally` clause:

```
import threading
import Queue
import sqlite3

class DBThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, myqueue, db_path):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.myqueue = myqueue
        self.db_path = db_path

    def run(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_path)

        try:
            while True:
                data = self.myqueue.get()    
                if data is None:    # check for sentinel value
                    break

                with conn:
                    conn.execute("INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES (?)", (data,))
                self.myqueue.task_done()
        finally:
            conn.close()


q = Queue.Queue()
for i in range(100):
    q.put(str(i))

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
conn.execute('create table if not exists test (data text)')
conn.close()

t = DBThread(q, 'test.db')
t.start()

q.join()
q.put(None)    # tell database thread to terminate
```

If you cannot use a sentinel value you can add a flag to the class that is checked in the `while` loop. Also add a `stop()` method to the thread class that sets the flag. You will need to use a non-blocking `Queue.get()`:

```
class DBThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, myqueue, db_path):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.myqueue = myqueue
        self.db_path = db_path
        self._terminate = False

    def terminate(self):
        self._terminate = True

    def run(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_path)

        try:
            while not self._terminate:
                try:
                    data = self.myqueue.get(timeout=1)
                except Queue.Empty:
                    continue

                with conn:
                    conn.execute("INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES (?)", (data,))
                self.myqueue.task_done()
        finally:
            conn.close()

....
q.join()
t.terminate()    # tell database thread to terminate
```

---

Finally, it's worth mentioning that your program could terminate if the db thread manages to drain the queue, i.e. if `q.join()` returns. This is because the db thread is a daemon thread and will not prevent the main thread exiting. You need to ensure that your worker threads produce enough data to keep the db thread busy, otherwise `q.join()` will return and the main thread will exit.

Comment: What does `with conn:` do in this case? Usually it cleans up resources (in this case the connection), which is not what we want at this point?

Comment: @Caramiriel: that's right, we do not want to clean up at that point. However, it does not do what you think;  it implements an automatic commit/rollback of the transaction. See [Using the connection as a context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager).